Why parent class Method2 can't be overridden?


class MainClass {
    constructor() { }
    
    Metod1(){
        console.log('MainClass.Metod1()');
    }
    Metod2 = () => console.log('MainClass.Metod2()');
}


class СhildClass extends MainClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    
    Metod1(){
        console.log('СhildClass.Metod1()');
    }
    Metod2() {
        console.log('СhildClass.Metod2()');
    }
}


let child = new СhildClass();
child.Metod1();     // => СhildClass.Metod1()
child.Metod2();     // => MainClass.Metod2()



Why method2 is called from parent class?
If you rewrite a method in a child class using an arrow function, it will be overridden. Where can I read about this?

You haven't defined any constructor methods? Does this answer your question?

@ScottMarcus, I added a constructor, nothing changed

Metod2 = () => creates an instance property, rather than a prototype method - so, why would you want that in the first place?

@JaromandaX, Ok. Where does child.Medod2 "disappear", how to call him?

Use an actual function definition, not an instance property, to define that method: Metod2() { console.log('MainClass.Metod2()'); }. Voting to close as a typographical issue.

@FragDealer it's on the prototype chain. But the property is directly on the instance shadowing the prototype. It's best to just not do any of that, if you want to leverage inheritance, and use regular methods. Mucking around with a mix of properties and methods is just adding unnecessary complexity.

NB: This is not a typographical issue. The asker didn't by accident use the arrow syntax.

Where does child.Medod2 "disappear" - "behind" the instance property Metod2. how to call him? - don't write bad code?
